# How to fulfill missing cells of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, missing-data, data-cleaning

I have a dataset like this.

```
df = data.frame( name= c("Tommy", "John", "Dan"), age = c(20, NA, NA) )
```

I tried to set 15 y.o. to John and Dan.

```
df[ ( df$age != 20) , ]$age = 15
```

But I got an error as follows,

> Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, (df$age != 20), , value = list(name = c(NA_integer_,  :    missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

What is a nice way to set new values to these missing cells?

Comment: `df[!df$age==20,"age"] <- 15`

Comment: Consider the return to `NA != 20`, which should make the problem obvious. Several people have provided solutions below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify all cells that are not 20, including other valid values for age, I would do the following:

```
# Creating a data frame with another valid age
df = data.frame( name= c("Tommy", "John", "Dan","Bob"), age = c(20, NA, NA,12) )

# Substitute values different than 20 for 15
df[df$age!=20 | is.na(df$age),"age"] <- 15

   name age
1 Tommy  20
2  John  15
3   Dan  15
4   Bob  15
```

Comment: Thanks, @Diego Rodrigues. I now understand taht is.na() is important. When slicing dataframe in R, not only "True" but "NA" extract records from the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df$age[is.na(df$age)] <- 15
```

or using your style of syntax:

```
df[is.na(df$age), ]$age = 15
```

The error you get arises because `df$age != 20` produces the following:

```
[1] FALSE    NA    NA
```

The `NA` values in the *age* column are not interpreted correctly as not being equal to twenty in the logical statement.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `is.na`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(age), age:= 15]
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. I now understand taht is.na() is important. When slicing dataframe in R, not only "True" but "NA" extract records from the dataset.